# Net-SNMP Custom MIB handlers

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I want to create custom MIB and custom controller for this mib. I use `Net-SNMP` and Agent device is Debian based Linux machine that `snmpd` installed on it.I created template and generated `.c` and `.h` files using `mib2c`. At this point, I don't know what to do with these generated files? I want to handle some (The ones I created in MIB) SNMP request in my `Clang` application. So basically, if I copy the source that `mib2c` generated to my `C` project, will it work? Shouldn't I need to register these handlers to snmpd?

I followed [this](http://openhpi.sourceforge.net/subagent-manual/index.html) tutorial, but It focused on writing the code. It didn't mention compiling and executing.

Answer (score 2):

After generating the .c and .h file you need to rebuild the netsnmp code again. To link your new `.c` and `.h` file into netsnmp, when you run the ./configure pass it as argument. (`./configure --with-mib-modules="Object"` where Object is the `.c/.h` filename). After that make using `make` command